# Page Boost on Solr with Sitecore

Tags: boost, solr, sitecore

I'm trying to set up the page boost (during index) of Sitecore (9.0.1) with Solr (6.6.2).
I've followed the tutorials provided by Sitecore and, for some reason, I always get the same score, no matter what the `__Boost` value is on the page and (subsequently) on the Solr Document.

I've also removed the Boost field from the excluded fields 
 in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`

If I query Solr I get inconsistent results. The Boost seems to not affect the Score at all.

[Document Score not affected by the boost value, searching for ONTSLAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oDLp.png)

Am I misunderstanding this whole functionality?

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Thanks in advance!